# dlib correlation tracker tracks object after object is out of frame

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, dlib

dlib correlation tracker detects object/person but when object/person is out of frame it still detects a object. If the object/person out of the frame When the camera stream starts, it detects nothing,  after object/person enters the frame it detects the object/person correctly, so The tracker updates itself. However, it didn't update itself, once the object/person out of frame.

the code below run on Raspberry Pi 3A+ with Rasbian Buster, opencv 4.1.0, dlib 19.24.99, with arguments:

```
python3 object-tracker.py --prototxt MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt --model MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel --label person
```

The below code is from [pyimagesearch](https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/10/22/object-tracking-with-dlib/). The input video argument removed since the video stream from camera used. The code is work as expected if the input video file used as shown in the source. However, the  tracker do not stop tracking once object is out of frame when camera stream used. prototxt and model files can be found [here](https://github.com/haroldss/pyimagesearch/tree/master/object-tracking-dlib).

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils.video import FPS
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import dlib
import cv2
import time

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", required=True, help="path o Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True, help="path to the Caffe pre-trained model")
ap.add_argument("-l", "--label", required=True, help="class label we are interested in")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", type=str, help="path to optional output video file")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.2, help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

CLASSES = ["background", "areoplane", "bicycle", "bird", "boat", "bottle", "bus", "car", "cat", "chair", "cow",
    "diningtable", "dog", "horse", "motorbile", "person", "pottedplant", "sheep", "sofa", "train", "tvmonitor"]

print("[INFO] loading model...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])

print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
tracker = None
writer = None
label = ""


fps = FPS().start()

while True:
    frame = vs.read()

    if frame is None:
        break

    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=300)
    frame = imutils.rotate(frame, angle=180)
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    if args["output"] is not None and writer is None:
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")
        writer = cv2.VideoWriter(args["output"], fourcc, 30, (frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), True)

    if tracker is None:
        (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 0.007843, (w, h), 127.5)

        net.setInput(blob)
        detections = net.forward()

        if len(detections) > 0:
            i = np.argmax(detections[0, 0, :, 2])

            conf = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
            label = CLASSES[int(detections[0, 0, i, 1])]

            if conf > args["confidence"] and label == args["label"]:
                box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
                (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

                tracker = dlib.correlation_tracker()
                rect = dlib.rectangle(startX, startY, endX, endY)
                tracker.start_track(rgb, rect)

                cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, startY - 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    else:
        tracker.update(rgb)
        pos = tracker.get_position()

        startX = int(pos.left())
        startY = int(pos.top())
        endX = int(pos.right())
        endY = int(pos.bottom())

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, startY - 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 255, 0), 2)


    if writer is not None:
        writer.write(frame)

    cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord("q"):
        break

    fps.update()

fps.stop()
print("[INFO] elapsed time: {:.2f}".format(fps.elapsed()))
print("[INFO] approx. FPS: {:.2f}".format(fps.fps()))

if writer is not None:
    writer.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect where dlib's correlation\_tracker lost the target image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39069480/how-do-i-detect-where-dlibs-correlation-tracker-lost-the-target-image)

Comment: You asked very good question - the tracker is good, but doesn't return losing moment . But you provided too much redundant information here, try to be more laconic. The answer is given by author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39069480/how-do-i-detect-where-dlibs-correlation-tracker-lost-the-target-image